# How do i Create a Pie Chart using Time duration as Parameters in C# Mine is not working

Tags: c#, charts, pie-chart

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    Dictionary<string, string> tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tags = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"Win", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()},
                {"Loss", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}                  
            };

        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("AreaPie");

        chart1.Legends.Add("Win");
        chart1.Legends.Add("Loss");
        chart1.Titles.Add("Average Holding Times");
        chart1.Series.Add("PChart");

        chart1.Series["PChart"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;

        foreach (string r in tags.Keys)
        {
            chart1.Series["PChart"].Points.AddXY(r, tags[r]);                
        }
    }
```

I was trying to create a Pie Chart that would have show me the time duration from a certain time range start to end and it would show me how much time was my winning streak and losing streak but after i created just a simple chart to show if it picks up my time value it won't even showed up already i debug this code and it has no error but it doesn't show a pie chart why is it? please do help i don't understand it why. i was just hoping for a simple pie chart with time duration parameters for a start up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the property on time:

```
        tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"WIN",DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()},
            {"LOOSE",DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()}                  
        };
```